# How can I prevent "[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'"

Tags: ios, nsarray

I've got a button action method that uses a loop counter, the loop runs 0 thru 9 then triggers another event. The problem I'm having is if the button is pressed more than 10 times it throws an `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]' error`. I know this means the button action has been initiated more times than the array is configured for, what I would like to know is how can I prevent the error from occurring? So that if the action is initiated more than 10 times the app doesn't crash with a `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]`. Any help would be great.

here is the Loop Counter:

```
-(void) gameLoop {

if (loopCounter < 10){
    revealArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", nil];
    cover1.alpha = 1.0;
    cover2.alpha = 1.0;
    cover3.alpha = 1.0;
    cover4.alpha = 1.0;
    cover5.alpha = 1.0;
    cover6.alpha = 1.0;
    cover7.alpha = 1.0;
    cover8.alpha = 1.0;
    coreView.alpha = 1.0;

NSDictionary *question = nil;

question = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter];

questionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[question objectForKey:@"imageNames"]];
[self getAnswers];
}
else {
    //NSLog(@"finished");

   [self animateResults];
}

}
```

this code creates the array:

```
-(void) getAnswers {

Tribes *tribes = [[Tribes alloc]init];
[tribes createArray];
answersArray = [[tribes optionsArray]mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *question = nil;
question = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:0];

 if ([[answersArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[question objectForKey:@"answers"]] || [[answersArray objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:[question objectForKey:@"answers"]]){
   [self getAnswers];
}

else {
    [self answerLabelMethod];
    NSLog(@"%@", answersArray);

    questionTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(revealImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES ];

}
}
```

Ive discovered the break point is in this method:

```
- (void) answerMethod:(int)answerBtn {

if (answerBtn == random) {
    //NSLog(@"correct!");
    int maxScore = 10000;
    int userScore = maxScore - (questionTimerCounter*1000);
    NSLog(@"%d", userScore);
    runningScore = runningScore + userScore;
    NSLog(@"%d" , runningScore);

    NSMutableDictionary *question = nil;
    //either at this point 
    question = [[questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter]mutableCopy];
    //
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"correct"];
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:userScore] forKey:@"score"];
    [questionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:loopCounter withObject:question];
        }
else {

    NSMutableDictionary *question = nil;
    //or this point
    question = [[questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter]mutableCopy];
    //
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"correct"];
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"score"];
    [questionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:loopCounter withObject:question];

}

GameInProgress = NO;

loopCounter++;
[self revealAnswer];

}
```

Comment: Post your code so can get better idea.

Comment: Check whether loopCounter is less than array size, then perform the task, else do nothing.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        
    }
should be exact like this, please check

Comment: i think you are trying to get object from array from the index which is out of scope of array like 10 or more.

Comment: what is the size of question array?

Comment: share your delegate methods

Comment: Update post to show array method

Comment: How could i disable the 3 IBAction buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your "question array" does not have that much capacity to access 11th element as it holds only 10 elements (0 to 9)

So put a breakpoint near this line and you will get some lead to fix the problem
question = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter];

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get object at index which is out of bound of array i think. put `breakpoint` whenever needed and check the arraysizes. add `exception breakpoint` to check where your app is crashing.